# Combine Arrays in JavaScript Without Duplicates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to combine `ccAddresses` and `toAddresses` values into just one set of array without duplication.

Expected Output

```
   { "newAddresses": ["john@gmail.com", "joshua@gmail.com", "jane@gmail.com", "james@gmail.com"] }
```

```js
const old = [
  {
    "ccAddresses": ["john@gmail.com", "joshua@gmail.com"],
  },
  { 
    "ccAddresses": ["jane@gmail.com", "joshua@gmail.com"],
    "toAddresses": ["jane@gmail.com", "james@gmail.com"],
  }
];

const news = old.flatMap((val, index) => ({
"newAddress": val.ccAddresses
}))

console.log(news)
```

Comment: applies only to `ccAddresses`? is expected output an object?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const res = Array.from(new Set([...old.flatMap(x => [...x.ccAddresses])]))
```

**UPDATED**(as per new author's requirement):

```
Array.from(new Set([...old.flatMap(x => [...x.ccAddresses].concat([...x.toAddresses || []]))]))
```

Comment: @Joseph Array.from(new Set([...old.flatMap(x => [...x.ccAddresses].concat([...x.toAddresses || []]))]))

Comment: What about this? `const res = Array.from(new Set([...old.flatMap(x => [...x.ccAddresses, ...x.toAddresses])]))`

Comment: Is that one ok too?

Comment: @Joseph if there is no `toAddresses ` it will be an exception, this is whi I added
`[...x.toAddresses || []]`